# SwiftUI: How to share multiple items with ShareLink

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-sharelink

I want to share images and text using ShareLink.

This is the code for sharing only one image.

```
ShareLink(item: image, preview: SharePreview(vm.post.text, image: image)) {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
       .font(.system(size: 20))
       .foregroundColor(Color("SpaceBlue"))
}
```

I tried like this

```
ShareLink(items: [image, vm.post.text], preview: SharePreview(vm.post.text, image: image)) {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
        .font(.system(size: 19))
        .foregroundColor(Color("SpaceBlue"))
}
```

How should ShareLink items be used?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I tried like this"—what happened?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
ShareLink(items: [image, vm.post.text], preview: {_ in SharePreview(vm.post.text, image: image)}) 
    {
        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
            .font(.system(size: 19))
            .foregroundColor(Color("SpaceBlue"))
    }
```